# Non prime modulus of prime powers

Tags: totient-function, fermat-numbers

Given a function $f(x,n) = x^{x^{x^{x}}}$ where $n = \text{how many powers of }x$,
how to find value of $f(x,n) \bmod k$, where $k < x$ and $k$ can be prime or not prime and has large values.

For example: $f(5,2) \bmod 3 = 5^5 \bmod 3 = 3125 \bmod 3 = 2.$

Comment: Where did you find this problem? Have you made any progress?

Comment: It was asked in a competition. I only know that Fermat's Little Theorem could help but that works if *k* is prime.
Maybe if I could find a prime *y* which is a divisor of *k* and use some modular arithmetic, that'd help. I don't know, I am confused.

Comment: Similar question on a StackExchange site, but the answer answers your question. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31803/computational-complexity-of-modular-power-towers-tetration. I would advise doing a google search on "modulus tetration"

Comment: Let $g(0) = k, g(n+1) = \varphi(g(n))$. Then you need to compute $f(x,l) \bmod g(l)$ for $l = n,n-1,\ldots,1$, because $\forall a, a^b \equiv a^c \bmod  m$ iff $b \equiv c \bmod \varphi(m)$